# discord bot won't play audio from a URL

Tags: node.js, discord.js, text-to-speech

I just switched to v12 and i'm trying to get the bot to play audio from a url (http://www.voicerss.org/api/)but it won't play audio and it doesn't show errors, it used to work perfectly with v11.

I've followed [this page](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html#voice) to update my code
Here is the code:

```
async execute(message, args) {
    url = `http://api.voicerss.org/?key=${process.env.VOICE_RSS_KEY}&hl=de-de&v=Jonas&c=MP3&f=16khz_16bit_stereo&src=`;
    let speech = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
      if (i == 0) {
        speech += args[i];
      } else {
        speech += '%20' + args[i];
      }
    }
    url = url.concat('', speech);

    const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
    if (!voiceChannel)
      return message.channel.send(
        'You need to be in a voice channel to use this command'
      );
    try {
      let connection = await voiceChannel.join();
      const dispatcher = connection.play(url);
      //console.log(dispatcher);
      console.log(url);
      dispatcher.on('finish', () => {
        connection.disconnect();
      });
    dispatcher.on('error', console.error);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return message.channel.send(err);
    }
  }
```